# After group by find the closest from each group in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas, and stuck into an calculation. This is my sample DF. I am interested to get the closest **strike_price** rows of **close** price for each group. (group by date, time, option_type)

```
        name      date   time      open      high       low     close       option_type  strike_price  open_opn  high_opn  low_opn  close_opn 
0       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      CE              11800       104.95    109.45   104.50     107.25 
1       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      CE              11700       160.00    164.25   159.90     161.60
2       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      CE              11600       223.20    229.10   223.20     226.30  
0       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      PE              11800       166.05    166.95   163.55     165.95  
1       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      PE              11600       88.80     89.45    86.45      89.00
2       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      PE              11700       122.35    122.65   119.40     122.30
```

This is my expected output.

```
        name      date   time      open      high       low     close       option_type  strike_price  open_opn  high_opn  low_opn  close_opn 

1       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11700.15      CE              11700       160.00    164.25   159.90     161.60
2       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11700.15      PE              11700       122.35    122.65   119.40     122.30
```

If close proce is 11760, expected o/p will be.

```
0       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      CE              11800       104.95    109.45   104.50     107.25
0       NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.10  11699.35  11720.15      PE              11800       166.05    166.95   163.55     165.95
```

Please help me on this. highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) first and then get minimal value per groups by [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['diff'] = df['close'].sub(df['strike_price']).abs()

df = df.sort_values('diff').drop_duplicates(['date', 'time', 'option_type'])
print (df)
    name      date   time      open     high       low     close option_type  \
1  NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.1  11699.35  11720.15          CE   
2  NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.1  11699.35  11720.15          PE   

   strike_price  open_opn  high_opn  low_opn  close_opn   diff  
1         11700    160.00    164.25    159.9      161.6  20.15  
2         11700    122.35    122.65    119.4      122.3  20.15
```

Another solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df['diff'] = df['close'].sub(df['strike_price']).abs()

df = df.loc[df.groupby(['date', 'time', 'option_type'])['diff'].idxmin()]
print (df)

    name      date   time      open     high       low     close option_type  \
1  NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.1  11699.35  11720.15          CE   
5  NIFTY  20180903  09:16  11736.05  11736.1  11699.35  11720.15          PE   

   strike_price  open_opn  high_opn  low_opn  close_opn   diff  
1         11700    160.00    164.25    159.9      161.6  20.15  
5         11700    122.35    122.65    119.4      122.3  20.15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jezrael. Highly appreciated your efforts.